# Need MYSQL database query solution

Tags: mysql, date, group-by, count, distinct

In MySQL I have the following table:

| date | work | code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 11:41:24 | 10 | 1 |
| 2022-01-01 10:41:24 | 10 | 1 |
| 2022-01-03 09:41:24 | 0 | 0 |
| 2022-02-04 06:41:24 | 10 | 1 |
| 2022-02-05 05:41:24 | 40 | 1 |

My SQL code:

```
SELECT extract(MONTH FROM date) AS month, count(number) AS sum_number FROM be WHERE code='1' group by month
```

This is the result of this code:

Result

| month | sum_work |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 20 |
| 2 | 50 |

How can I get this result and what do I need to change in my query?

work_days: each month how many day did they work

Final Result:

| month | work_days | sum_work |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 20 |
| 2 | 2 | 50 |

Comment: Please [edit] your question to tell us what the `workd_days` column means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must count the distinct dates:

```
SELECT MONTH(date) AS month,   
       COUNT(DISTINCT DATE(date)) AS work_days, 
       COUNT(*) AS sum_number -- or SUM(work) as your expected result
FROM be 
WHERE code='1' 
GROUP BY month;
```

Comment: Thx! One more question if I want to multiply the result of work_days with 10? where should I add it?

Comment: @TóthLászló `10 * COUNT(DISTINCT DATE(date))` will work.

Answer (score 0):

If my guess is correct about your requirement, you want the number of days in each month having one or more records.

You can try something like this:

```sql
SELECT LAST_DAY(date) AS month_ending, 
       COUNT(number) AS sum_number
       COUNT (DISTINCT DATE(date)) AS workd_days
  FROM be 
  WHERE code='1'
 GROUP BY LAST_DAY(DATE)
```

[LAST_DAY(date)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_last-day) is a better choice than EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date), because `2021-01-06` and `2022-01-06` both return 1 from the latter.